# Android app crashes creating opening Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

My Android App "E-Mail" crashes when I try to open the "ReadActivity".

The method OpenMail(), declared in MainActivity, should start ReadActivity:

```
public void OpenMail(View v, int index) {
    String[] mail = {"x", "y", "z"};

    Intent readIntent = new Intent(this, ReadActivity.class); <-- Error occurs here

    readIntent.putExtra("mail", mail);

    startActivity(readIntent);
}
```

The method is called in the ListViewAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder = new Holder();

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);

    holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    holder.txvSenderMail = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txvSender);
    holder.txvSubject = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txvSubject);

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(ImageID[position]);
    holder.txvSenderMail.setText(SenderMail[position]);
    holder.txvSubject.setText(Subject[position]);

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new MainActivity().OpenMail(v, position);
        }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

> > The error:                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference

I hope anybody can help me!
Thank you!

Comment: put codes of ReadActivity too

Comment: Please put the code of your listview_item.xml file

Comment: I think that's not important, because the app crashes before starting the activity!

Answer (score 2):

You are actually trying to create new MainActivity when you do

```
new MainActivity().OpenMail(v, context, position);
```

I think you wanted to do something like this, if you are currently at MainActivity class:

```
getActivity().OpenMail(v, context, position);
```

Of course, dont forget to add ReadActivity to AndroidManifest

Comment: or just `OpenMail(v, context, position);`

Comment: I can't use getActivity() or only OpenMail because the method call is in the Class ListViewAdapter and the Method is in the class MainActivity!

Comment: How are you creating your adapter? Like this?
public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {   
}. Then youll have the context, which is your activity. Then use if(context instanceof MainActivity){
                ((MainActivity)mContext). OpenMail();
            }